# Можно ли запустить консольное приложение Свифт на Винде?

Tags: windows, swift

Написал мини-приложение на свифт на виндоус. Пока нет доступа к макушке, я хочу запустить его в cmd на Винде. Через какие IDEA/команды в строке можно протестить консольное приложение, с которым можно взаимодействовать?

Answer (score 0):

Читайте здесь [Introducing Swift on Windows](https://swift.org/blog/swift-on-windows/)